# omega where to make changes?

Tags: theming

I've installed Omega 7.x-4.2 and created my subtheme and I just want to start practising making changes with page.tpl.php and css but there are just so many files and so far nothing has affected change.

I copied over page.tpl.php found in omega/system folder and placed it in my subtheme/templates then placed styles in my subtheme/css/subtheme.hacks.css but see no changes at all.

Also have noticed in sites/all/themes the path structure is different for omega that is all/themes/omega/(ohm)omega/templates and in other
all/themes/subtheme/templates. I set this up a while ago following documentation and can't remember why it has ended up this way and whether or not that would cause problems. There are no errors just no changes taking effect.

Just all seems so unnecessarily complicated!

Comment: Omega 4 is working with SASS so it will be wrong to modify the CSS files manually

Comment: Which parts of the documentation do you not understand? Please be specific, or this is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: I'd really suggest going through the tutorials on level up tuts http://leveluptuts.com/tutorials/drupal-tutorials/the-complete-guide-to-omega

Comment: @Clive I don't understand which is the MAIN css file that will affect change and which template just to get started. I see no changes take effect.

Comment: cea, documentation says not to do it, and use SASS. There literally **is no main CSS file you should change**. And if you insist, @Kevin linked a tutorial. Have you seen it? #7?

Comment: @Molot yes that's how i created subtheme with levelup but i really am better just diving in after the fact so was hoping for a heads up

Comment: Plus level up suggests using drush however i use recommended release and not alpha 7 so am doing manually - anyway

Comment: its prob beyond me at this point- too complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omega 4 is essentially built around using [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) for styling.  It's not a requirement, but the starterkit almost assumes it.

Assuming you have created a proper subtheme from the starterkit, you should have a directory called "sass".  These are the files you would change.  Peruse the README.md that is in there.  A basic SASS file structure for partials is set up, and I find that it maps fairly well to Drupal.  Each subdirectory also has a README.md.  Nothing forces you to use this structure for your partials, but I like it.

After this, you need a working SASS environment.  Everything should be there to get bundler going to install the gems you need.  Personally, I move all of the SASS and other build files out of the theme, and to my project root folder.  Then I have a single Gruntfile for making and deploying my project.

Comment: I think you've answered my question as not happy I am about it. Just because I think this whole SYSTEM is screwed.

Comment: @cea As much as it is a pain to set up, more and more F/OSS projects are using SASS.  It has more or less become a defacto standard now.  After working with SASS for a while now, I really hate going back to work plain CSS projects.  Omega includes also work nicely into this scheme.  Every template file I add to my custom theme gets a custom preprocess include, and also gets its own SASS partial.  It make is very easy to find things, which is especially nice with complicated themes.

Comment: fair enough- I will do the homework. thank you for your time and input.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things you can check...

- In your subtheme, have you declared omega as your base theme in the .info file?

> ```
> name = omega sub theme
> description = my sub theme
> base theme = omega
> ```

- Have you enabled your subtheme as the default theme in admin/appearance?
- Have you flushed the cache after making changes? ( configuration > development > performance > clear cache )
- In dev tools, or whatever you use to inspect an element, when you have the source open, what is the path? Is it definitely coming from your sub theme folder?

Comment: Yes, all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

A SASS environment is not a strict requirement for writing CSS in Omega. It has provision for directly editing CSS. SASS makes things a lot easier.

Have you added your CSS file in the theme's info file? Did you clear the cache after that?

Don't follow Ohm(the sample theme which ships with Omega 4) as a standard. It is bleeding edge and not recommended for production use.

If you create the subtheme using the drush subtheme wizard command(drush owiz), it will create a subtheme with sensible defaults which is easier to get started with.

Comment: I did it manually but you know what I give you points for understanding it all because honestly it is a mess for me right now.